# How can I implement sign in with Google / Apple for a decoupled site?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have a decoupled Drupal site that uses JSON:API to serve an [Ionic React](https://ionicframework.com/) app.

I'm currently using the [JWT (JSON Web Token Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt) module to enable users to register and log in (alongside the [Get JWT on Login module](https://www.drupal.org/project/getjwtonlogin)) to the app/Drupal site.

I have used the [Email Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration) module so that users only need to provide an email address and password to log in, so the sign-up form is very simple.

Now, I want to integrate "sign in with Google" and "sign in with Apple" functionality to make it easier for users on Android and iOS.

Requirements

- I want to use the Google/Apple services directly if possible; I don't want to pay for some third-party service that might disappear and leave my user accounts stranded.  (For example, [Auth0, one of the major "authentication as a service" providers, abandoned their Drupal module with only 6 months' notice.](https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-drupal/issues/180))
- It needs to work with decoupled login.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, it doesn't seem like a ready-made solution is available yet for Drupal 9.

**Solution: OpenID Connect**

One solution is to use the [OpenID Connect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) with the [Simple OAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth) module or the [OAuth2 Server module](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth2_server).  These modules do similar things but OAuth2 Server is less opinionated/more complex to set up.

OpenID Connect module provides support for Google out of the box; Apple support needs to be written, but [work is ongoing here](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect/issues/3232712#comment-14269310).

**Solution: Social Auth**

The [Social Auth](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth) family of modules provides both [Google](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth_google/) and [Apple](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth_apple) submodules; however, the [Social Auth Decoupled](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth_decoupled) module does not have a Drupal 9 release, and it is [looking for a new maintainer](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth_decoupled/issues/3216823).

At a minimum, Social Auth Decoupled and [Social Auth Google API](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth_google_api) would  need to be updated for Drupal 9, and a `Social Auth Sign in with Apple` module would need to be written.

So, **Social Auth** is good if you don't need decoupled login, but if you do need decoupled, you will be writing a lot of code on your own.